# My laptop's fans went crazy after resume from suspend

Tags: suspend, fan

I've resumed my laptop from suspend mode while ago and its fan has started to work very loud immediately. Never I had seen this laptop making that much noise. Room temperature was around 18 C and computer itself was also cool. CPU temperature was around 35 C when I checked with:

watch -n 2 sensors

I've suspended the pc and resumed again. Now, it's working quite as normal. What could have wrong here?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem or is it a fluke?  If you can reproduce the problem, keep open a resource monitor and look for a process that is taking a large share of resources when the fans ramp up. If it's a fluke and you can't reproduce the issue, we aren't going to be able to troubleshoot a problem that existed for a brief period of time that no longer happens. If I had to guess, it was a process that demanded a lot of resources when the device woke up.

Comment: It was fluke. There were some open browser tabs but I don't think it would cause a high load on the cpu.